# java.lang.ClassCastException: Fragment cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, androidx

I am creating a todo kotlin application for a university assignment, running on Android level 33. When I try to run the application, I get this error among others:

*"java.lang.ClassCastException: com.leedsbeckett.todo_application.fragments.list.ListFragment cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment"*

Here is the code of ListFragment.kt:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.leedsbeckett.todo_application.R

class ListFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mTaskViewModel: TaskViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

        // Recyclerview
        val adapter = ListAdapter()
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        // UserViewModel
        mTaskViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TaskViewModel::class.java)
        mTaskViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { user ->
            adapter.setData(user)
        })

        view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.floatingActionButton).setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_addFragment)
        }

        return view
    }

}
```

Any relevant questions on the matter are either unanswered or outdated, what am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing the full stack trace that we need to see where this issue is occurring.

Comment: Add stacktrace along with activity code where you are using this fragment

Comment: Just off the top of my head, your val view portion when inflated you have it as false.. change it to true and see what happens.